# what does the phrase “as also that of” mean?

Tags: meaning

Anglicanism was coined to describe the common religious tradition of these churches; ｛as also that of ｝the Scottish Episcopal Church, which, though originating earlier within the Church of Scotland, had come to be recognised as sharing this common identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an abbreviated reference, to save having to say the same thing twice...

> Anglicanism was coined to describe *the common religious tradition* of these churches; as also [*(to describe) the common religious tradition]* of the Scottish Episcopal Church

Answer (score 1):

**that** = relative (anaphoric) pronoun referring back to an earlier noun or noun-phrase

**as** = in the same way, similarly

**also**  = in addition, as well, too

and also too that [i.e. *the common religious tradition*] of the Scottish Episcopal Church

Compare:

> This "Renaissance" of the Latin language (as also that of ancient Greek) did not start any earlier than the 8th-9th century.

as also *the "Renaissance" of ancient Greek*...

and the "Renaissance" of ancient Greek as well